# How do I count unique names?

Tags: python

I am trying to count up unique names that start with "From:" from a file name. However, I keep getting a long list of numbers. What is my code actually reading and how do I fix this?

```
count = 0
name = []
fname = input("What is your file name? Enter it here: ")

try:
    fname = open(fname)
    name = set(f.readlines()) 
except:
    print ("That file does not exist.")
for name in fname:
    if name.startswith("From:"):
        count = len(name)  
        print (count)
```

Comment: You print length of names, not its count.

Comment: where is fname defined or what it contains?

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of `set` to hold all required names and find its length to get the count:

```
file_name = input("What is your file name? Enter it here: ")

s = set()
with open(file_name) as f:
    for name in f:
        if name.startswith('From:'):
            s.add(name)

print(len(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
words = []
count = 0

with open ("unique.txt","r") as f:
    # Get a list of lines in the file and covert it into a set
    words = set(f.readlines()) 
FromWords=[]  
for word in words:
    if word.startswith("From:"):
        FromWords.append(word)

print(len(FromWords))
```

First, we filter out all duplicate words and then look for the words which start with From: and this may aid in faster processing if you're dealing with the big amount of data.

let me know if you need any help in this regard.

Comment: let me know if you need any help in this regard and if you think my answer has helped you solve the problem, please consider accepting the answer and upvote my answer. Thanks